# Broke the rules on pre-interview online technical assessment – will I get blacklisted?

Tags: interviewing, tech-industry, online, assessment

I'm a STEM student who is going to graduate soon and wish to enter the tech/data science sector. I heard from friends that an easy way to get interview experience is to apply to companies that one is not necessarily too keen on (so one doesn't care if they provide you an offer or not), and so I started doing this without taking the process too seriously. Some time ago I took an "online assessment" from a certain well-known test-provider for data science. The instructions of the test explicitly said that any copying of their materials or navigating out of the browser window is forbidden.

Now, again, I didn't care much whether I get the job or not, I was only interested in the test for the sake of practice. So I took this test using a safari browser whilst using cmd+shift+3 to take screenshots (for later study and to share with mates) and also freely leaving the browser window to use my calculator, answer messages on whatsapp and check facebook. I figured it wouldn't matter if they "caught" me.

However, I recently heard that these test-providers could potentially "blacklist" people who "cheat". I unfortunately didn't think about this consequence before I decided to break the rules of this test provider. Even worse, I found out that they're used by a fair few companies that I'm actually very interested working in. I'm now worried that I'll be blacklisted, potentially without them even telling me.

Is this a realistic concern? If so, should I do something or just wait and see? Should I contact the test-provider and admit to what I've done, or just leave it be?

Comment: What makes you think they know you cheated?

Comment: @Kilisi I assume they're able to track my keystrokes and know when I leave the browser window. I'm on a MacOS system.

Comment: Just leave it be and in the future follow the rules as you would in a real interview.  Candidates who can't/won't follow directions are usually not hired.

Comment: browser tabs can't track key activity outside of a focused tab, for security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now successfully applied to multiple other organisations that use similar tests without any blacklisting. So it all went fine.

For others who have to face these mindless iq/numeracy/programming/knowledge tests, I suggest the following strategy:

1. Make an alias account (fake email, resume, etc.) and use it to send off job applications. The companies will then typically send you some automated online test. Do this test while making sure to take photos of each question using your phone or some other **external** camera.
2. Go through the questions in detail at your own pace at home, making sure to understand exactly the structure of the problems. After doing enough of these tests, you'll start to see patterns and become progressively better at them.
3. Having sent applications to many companies within an industry and done their tests, you should now have a good understanding of how things work. Repeat steps 1 and 2 with new fake alias accounts until you're starting to get through the testing stages (but never do a live interviews using an alias account, obviously). Once you've reached this point, you can finally begin sending proper applications and expect to easily get through the online assessments stage and straight to the real interviews.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a realistic concern?

Unlikely, mainly for technical reasons. They probably would blacklist you, if they find out, but it's unlikely that they will find out (unless you do more stupid things)

> If so, should I do something or just wait and see?

You should STOP cheating and breaking rules agreed to. You should NOT share the screenshots (or even the fact that you did this) with your mates but delete them. You should NOT share any of this on social media, etc.

> Should I contact the test-provider and admit to what I've done

No. I don't think it would help at this point. Learn your lesson and move on.

You are looking at this the wrong way. Hiring is NOT about getting 18 out of 20 questions right. It's about whether you are a good fit for the job and vice versa. If you get hired for the wrong role everyone will be miserable, including you. Not getting the job is often the "best" outcome for you, even if it doesn't feel like that at the time.

This works best if everyone is as honest and transparent as they can be. It's in your own best interest not to cheat or pretend to be something that you are not. Lying and cheating are some of the WORST things you can do. It's morally and ethically wrong, it's an offense that will get you blacklisted if it comes out, and it's unlikely to help so it's also stupid.

Let's consider this: you successfully pretend to have a skill that you don't and manage to get away with it and land the job. The job actually requires the skill, so you need to try like crazy to catch up. a) you need to work long hours, b) you still not delivering on time and at the level expected which makes you miserable & stressed, c) your manager is unhappy too and tries to figure out why this is not working, d) eventually you get found out, get fired and blacklisted with a big ding on your resume.

Is that what you want?

Comment: Part of whether you're a good fit also includes whether the company can trust you. OP has shown that at best they are incapable of following simple instructions, and at worse they are a dishonest cheat - both of which are huge red flags for anyone looking to hire them.

Comment: This is a really good answer to explain why cheating doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing their infrastructure it seems unlikely that you will be found out unless you volunteer the information. Keystroke logging and other things external to your browser are not something that websites can control assuming you didn't install an application of some sort first.

But you're absolutely right that most places would blacklist you if you were caught cheating.